# Proyecto MVC pasar Valores de una variable del método GET al método POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo la siguiente linea de código en mi método GET:

```
    // GET: Areas/Edit/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        var Str = areas.NOMBRE;
```

y capturar `str` en el método POST:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = ....)] Areas areas)
    {
        string StrPost = Str; //str que debe venir del get
```

No se si utilizando un `viewbag` (no quiero que se lleve al View) o que variable 
utilizar ... ya he tenido `str` como variable global pero siempre que ingresa al método POST borra el contenido de `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso que planteas, lo mas recomendable es usar **Cookies** para almacenar tu variable de manera **Global** y a nivel de **Usuario**.

Aún así, puedes almacenar tu variable en `TempData[]`, y la podrás utilizar ***sólo en el siguiente Request*** (`[HttpPost] Edit()`):

```
// GET: Areas/Edit/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    TempData["Str"] = areas.NOMBRE;
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = ....)] Areas areas)
{
    string StrPost = TempData["Str"]; //str que debe venir del get
```

Como te comento, yo utilizaría **Cookies** (mejor encriptadas). En este artículo podrás ver como hacerlo en ASP.NET MVC:

[Encriptar y desencriptar cookies en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/9/19/encriptar-y-desencriptar-cookies-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-aspnet-mvc)

**UPDATE:**

Cosas a tener en cuenta sobre **`TempData[]`**:

- `TempData` se puede usar para almacenar datos entre dos solicitudes
  consecutivas. Los valores de `TempData` se conservarán durante la
  redirección (Request). `TempData` es un tipo `TempDataDictionary`.
- `TempData` utiliza internamente `Session` para almacenar los datos. Así
  que piensa en ello como una sesión de corta duración.
- El valor de `TempData` debe ser de tipo `Cast` antes de su uso. Verifica
  los valores nulos para evitar errores de tiempo de ejecución.
- `TempData` se puede usar para almacenar solo mensajes únicos como
  mensajes de error, mensajes de validación o variables de corto
  recorrido.
- Utiliza **`TempData.Keep()`** para mantener todos los valores de `TempData`
  en una tercera solicitud.

Comment: Y con el TempData[] el browser guarda el string? o donde almacena el valor del String

Comment: @ger: Buena pregunta ... TemData[] utiliza la sesión (Session) para almacenar la información, o sea, en el Servidor.

Comment: justo lo que necesito, no accesible en el cliente! :) :)

Comment: @ger. Ten en cuenta que si utilizas **Cookies encriptadas**, su contenido tampoco será "entendible" por el Cliente. –